# electrical lightng earth wire and neutral wire the same colour

Tags: electrical

i'm in the uk, and I've taken the wall lights off and the earth wire and the neutral are both black, how do I tell which is which. thank you john

Comment: Can you post a photo of this situation?

Comment: If you're able to figure this out, label the wires for next time.

Answer (score 1):

Most domestic fixed wiring in the UK is done with what is known as "twin and earth" cable. Normal twin and earth cable has two insulated conductors colored brown and blue* on cable produced today and colored red and black on earlier cables. In addition it has an uninsulated earth conductor.

Unlike the americans, we brits place sleeving over bare earth conductors inside boxes. This sleeving would normally be green/yellow striped, but on very old installations it may be plain green**.

Some properties are also wired with single wires in conduit, in the case of single wires in conduit there may not be a dedicated earth wire as the conduit can be used as the earth path.

If the light is fed with a cable, then what has most likely happened is that someone ran out of the proper earth sleeving, so they used a bit of black insulation stripped off another wire to sleeve the earth conductor. If this has happened it should be visible on a careful visual inspection, it's almost impossible to push tightly fitting insulation back onto a wire, so if this has been done then the insulation will likely have been taken from a large size of wire and will be a loose fit on the conductor.

If the wiring is in conduit then things get much more complicated. It's possible that someone used the wrong color wire, but it's equally possible that neither of the wires is in-fact a ground. For example one could be an incoming neutral and the other could be a neutral going out to the next light.

To test earths, I would suggest the following. First turn off power at the main switch, do not use the MCB for this as MCBs normally only provide single pole isolation***.

Then attach a long lead to the earthing system. I would suggest wiring it to the earth terminal of a plug and plugging it in is the easiest way.

You can then use your multimeter on continuity mode to find stuff that is connected to the earthing system.

P.S. It is always good practice to look carefully and label stuff *before* disconnection to avoid confution later.

* Normally live and neutral, but twin and earth cable is also used for switch drops with live and switched live. In this case the blue/black conductor should be marked with red/brown sleeving, but that does not always actually happen.

** In UK fixed wiring green/yellow replaced plain green for Earth long before brown/blue replaced red/black for live and neutral.

*** This advice on how to isolate both live and neutral applies specifically to the UK, n some countries even the main switch does not disconnect neutral and the only way to disconnect it would be to remove wires.

Answer (score -1):

Make a test lamp ( a simple bulb connected to two wires). Connect one wire of the test lamp to the live wire and then using the other wire touch the black wires one by one. The bulb will turn on normally and brightly when joined to the neutral wire. It will be dim when you touch the ground wire. Or there are chances that the bulb will not turn on in case the ground has been disconnected in your house.

Comment: If the circuit is protected by RCD, when the light is connected between line and ground the RCD will trip.

Comment: Don't bypass it. If the RCD trips, then you know the wire you are testing is the earth ground.

Comment: Sorry this answer is just plain wrong, in the absense of a RCD unless the earth is terrible then you are likely to get the same results testing with a bulb between live and earth as between live and neutral. If the earth *is* terrible then merely doing this test could create a severe hazard. If there is a RCD then connecting a lamp between live and earth will trip it, but unless the CU has been changed relatively recently an installation old enough to have red/black wiring probablly will not have a RCD on the lights.

Comment: Hmm okay after reading the answer you have posted I realised I shouldn't have written an answer since I don't know about the wiring in UK. I apologise for that. Apart from that if I would have known that a multimeter is common in every household and that the original poster would be having it, then I would have also given him somewhat same suggestion that you have. Anyway thanks increasing my knowledge.